# Extracting skin data from an FBX file

Tags: c++, animation, directx, fbx

I need to convert animation data from Autodesk's FBX file format to one that is compatible with DirectX; specifically, I need to calculate the offset matrices for my skinned mesh. I have written a converter( which in this case converts .fbx to my own 'scene' format ) in which I would like to calculate an offset matrix for my mesh. Here is code:

```
//
//  Skin
//
if(bHasDeformer)
{
    // iterate deformers( TODO: ACCOUNT FOR MULTIPLE DEFORMERS )
    for(int i = 0; i < ncDeformers && i < 1; ++i)
    {
        // skin
        FbxSkin *pSkin = (FbxSkin*)pMesh->GetDeformer(i, FbxDeformer::eSkin);
        if(pSkin == NULL)
            continue;

        // bone count
        int ncBones = pSkin->GetClusterCount();

        // iterate bones
        for (int boneIndex = 0; boneIndex < ncBones; ++boneIndex)
        {                       
            // cluster
            FbxCluster* cluster = pSkin->GetCluster(boneIndex);

            // bone ref
            FbxNode* pBone = cluster->GetLink();

            // Get the bind pose
            FbxAMatrix bindPoseMatrix, transformMatrix;
            cluster->GetTransformMatrix(transformMatrix);
            cluster->GetTransformLinkMatrix(bindPoseMatrix);

            // decomposed transform components
            vS = bindPoseMatrix.GetS();
            vR = bindPoseMatrix.GetR();
            vT = bindPoseMatrix.GetT();

            int *pVertexIndices = cluster->GetControlPointIndices();
            double *pVertexWeights = cluster->GetControlPointWeights();

            // Iterate through all the vertices, which are affected by the bone
            int ncVertexIndices = cluster->GetControlPointIndicesCount();

            for (int iBoneVertexIndex = 0; iBoneVertexIndex < ncVertexIndices; iBoneVertexIndex++) 
            {
                // vertex
                int niVertex = pVertexIndices[iBoneVertexIndex];

                // weight
                float fWeight = (float)pVertexWeights[iBoneVertexIndex];
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I convert the fbx transforms to a bone offset matrix?

Comment: It has been a long time since I tried importing an Fbx file like you are doing. I use the Asset Importer library to import different kinds of 3D models. I know this is not what you asked for, but thought that maybe I should suggest this. There seem to be a lot of tutorials out there for using assimp.

Comment: @malhotraprateek The Asset Importer Library doesn't include Autodesk Filmbox files(.fbx). It is, however, useful for many other file formats